# Tailwind full height scrollable divs

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to have the Search div full width above the three dark gray right columns (but keep the two left sidebars full height) Any ideas? I can't figure out how to get the search above the right side without losing the ability to scroll.

```
  <div class="flex flex-row h-screen">
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-red-200 w-12 flex-none"></div>
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-blue-200 w-64 flex-none">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="flex flex-row flex-auto">
      <div class="flex flex-row flex-auto">
        <div class="flex flex-none">Search</div>

        <div class="flex flex-row flex-auto">
          <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-50 w-1/5">
            <div class="h-16 items-center flex-none bg-gray-500">Left</div>
            <div class="flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll ewfwe fewf wef ewf ewf ewf ewfwe</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll Last</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-200 w-3/5">
            <div class="h-16 items-center flex-none bg-gray-500">Middle</div>
            <div class="flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll Last</div>
            </div>
            <div class="h-32 bg-blue-400 flex-none">
              <div>Bottom</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-400 w-1/5">
            <div class="h-16 items-center flex-none bg-gray-500">Right</div>
            <div class="flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
              <div class='py-16'>>Scroll Last</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Here's an example:**
https://www.codeply.com/p/oD37JtVW8s

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your stipulations correctly:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row h-screen">
  <div class="flex flex-col bg-red-200 w-12 flex-none"></div>
  <div class="flex flex-col bg-blue-200 w-32 flex-none">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="flex flex-col grow">
    <div class="flex flex-none">Search</div>
    <div class="flex flex-row flex-auto min-h-0">
      <div class="flex flex-row flex-auto">
        <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-50 w-1/5">
          <div class="h-16 items-center flex-none bg-gray-500">Left</div>
          <div class="flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll ewfwe fewf wef ewf ewf ewf ewfwe</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll Last</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-200 w-3/5">
          <div class="h-16 items-center flex-none bg-gray-500">Middle</div>
          <div class="flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll Last</div>
          </div>
          <div class="h-32 bg-blue-400 flex-none">
            <div>Bottom</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-400 w-1/5">
          <div class="h-16 items-center flex-none bg-gray-500">Right</div>
          <div class="flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>Scroll</div>
            <div class='py-16'>>Scroll Last</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have the search `<div>` be in a vertical flex layout, as opposed to your current horizontal flex layout. Use `min-height: 0` to override the implicit `min-height: min-content` so the scrollable elements conform to the height constraint imposed by the top-level `<div>` element.